# Plot Projects - MyNotificationOpenReceiver.class not getting triggered, why?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, geofencing

**Android**

-Initialization of plot is done successfully and latitude and longitude is also getting printed in debug log.

-But MyNotificationOpenReceiver is not getting triggered in android 5.1+.

**In manifest:**

`<receiver android:exported="false" android:name=".MyNotificationOpenReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.activationmobileapp.ready2ride.plot.OpenNotification" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>`

**Reciever class**:

```
public class MyNotificationOpenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    FilterableNotification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra("notification");
    if (notification.getData() == null)
        return;

    Intent openIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    openIntent.setAction("com.activationmobileapp.ready2ride.plot.OpenNotification");
    openIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    Log.e("debug", "onReceive: " );
    context.startActivity(openIntent);
}
}
```

**Main avtivity:**

```
 Plot.init(this);
```

**gradle:**

```
 compile 'com.plotprojects:plot-android:2.3.0-beta'
```

Comment: Please improve your question by following the guidelines outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://www.plotprojects.com/documentation/#Android_Custom), the broadcastreceiver must also be registered in the AndroidManifest. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes added is manifest

<receiver android:exported="false" android:name=".MyNotificationOpenReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.activationmobileapp.ready2ride.plot.OpenNotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: I got fcm RemoteMessage as below
  { google.sent_time=1507556256890,
   from=/topics/hpGGmXsBYY9sMs7G_android,  plot=H4sIAAAAAAAAAK1Ru27DMAz8F81GIMl2/OiWxejQoigyNAgyKBStCHUkQ5JRFIH/vXSSJVM7lIuIE3l3JC9snI6Dha3/RMdadhq77vwRN7tdE19i1bGMGfQ9OsBXn2xvQSXrXWTt/sIimjO6dEXegh8xJIvL1yFjg79VsvbCBsrSpJG1Ml9xXkkuxFLhzB2u5KrkZcHXormGnDMG3g/af7ku+Gm86ZklJZN9UQNqBJ3rvqjK/FjWCDXxFkI2vW6egEMpBQcBuS7WTVlL2fBCr2tdl8caNE0VEbzTxCvm7O/Mj400plZJUR/hVv+TszPGqAxthUVQERZEJTi9K7eAkvPsYfHPi5f9787JbLLEPSp3P9FJOT1g2H6Pi1hAMw0qkFwK1hgMhJEGvfNh/gHnTUiVJwIAAA==,   google.message_id=0:1507556257283845%07b1db99f9fd7ecd}